# Local network connection: LAN - WLAN works, WLAN - WLAN does not

Tags: wireless-networking, lan

My network is managed by the [TP-Link TL-WR840N router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WR840N.html) and provides both LAN and WLAN channels.

I have my laptop with local static IP 192.168.0.113 which is connected via WLAN. On the laptop runs a Tomcat 8 under 8088 port. If I connect to it from a Raspberry PI, which is connected via LAN, everything works just fine.

Although if I try to connect to the very same laptop from other devices over WLAN, I get `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` in Chrome or `EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)` in Android.

What am I doing wrong? What should I check in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might have wireless isolation mode on (which stops wifi clients talking directly to each other).

It's accessed in the menu's of the router under

- Wireless
- - Wireless Advanced
- - - Enable AP Isolation

Comment: Strange thing... Originally the `Enable AP Isolation` was unchecked, and wireless clients couldn't see each other. Then I checked it (no effect), and unchecked it again. And then it worked! So, I assume, that original value was true, and it was not properly displayed in the UI

Answer (score 0):

point the addresses to a valid dedicated IP that will route correctly rather than object.

Check advanced settings for Wireless.

Comment: A bit more explanation would be good ... as it stands it doesn't really answer the question. "What am I doing wrong? What should I check in the first place?"